# Mergesort implementation in C++

Tags: c++, mergesort

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int*,int*,int,int,int);
void mergesort(int *a, int*b, int low, int high)
{
int pivot;
if(low<high)
{
    pivot=(low+high)/2;
    mergesort(a,b,low,pivot);
    mergesort(a,b,pivot+1,high);
    merge(a,b,low,pivot,high);
}
}
void merge(int *a, int *b, int low, int pivot, int high)
{
int h,i,j,k;
h=low;
i=low;
j=pivot+1;

while((h<=pivot)&&(j<=high))
{
    if(a[h]<=a[j])
    {
        b[i]=a[h];
        h++;
    }
    else
    {
        b[i]=a[j];
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
**if(h>pivot)
{
    for(k=j; k<=high; k++)
    {
        b[i]=a[k];
        i++;
    }
}
else
{
    for(k=h; k<=pivot; k++)
    {
        b[i]=a[k];
        i++;
    }
}**
for(k=low; k<=high; k++) a[k]=b[k];
}

int main()
{
int a[] = {12,10,43,23,-78,45,123,56,98,41,90,24};
int num;

num = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

int b[num];

mergesort(a,b,0,num-1);

for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
cout<<endl;
}
```

I am not able to understand one thing in this code. This was given in my book.
I traced this code as to what happens if I take 8 unsorted numbers.

Why are we doing this? ( Portion with two stars at beginning and end )

```
if ( h > pivot )
{
......
}
else
{
......
}
```

The while loop above it will itself place only the sorted elements ( and all of them ) in the array b. And then we can finally, put it in the array a ( by the last for loop ).
I tried running the code without the marked portion, and it obviously shows the wrong answer, but I am not able to deduce why it is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: from CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43303/23476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code will merge remaining elements. For example if you have {3,4} and {1,2,6,7}
to merged then the part above this `if(h>pivot)` condition gives {1,2,3,4}.

So to copy rest elements we use this conditions.

Comment: I am a beginner in this, that is why having this doubt, is it possible that we can have such unequal sizes while merge sort? If we have the size of the input array as an even number, it gets divided into two equal halves, else if it is an odd number, it gets divided like, the (int) (inputsize/2) and this value + 1. So, is it possible that one size can be 4 and other can be 2 during sometime of execution of code?

Comment: Actually, the code divides it into half as you said. However, take example like {1,2,3} and {4,5,6} to be merged. So now merging will result in comparisons and copy {1,2,3} from first array to merged array. But still 4,5,6 are left to be merged. I was talking in that sense... when intermediate results become unbalanced.

Comment: See, you seem to a bit confused. For simplest example let us merge 2 elements. Merge 1 and 2. So pivot=(0+1)/2=0. So copying 1 to merged array first makes h=1. So h>pivot so && condition is no more valid. So it goes to `if-else` condition about which you are having doubt.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got what you meant.

Comment: Glad to help :D. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if your doubt is solved :P.

Answer (score 1):

This is when you merge the arrays, and you reached the end of one array, this is to copy other elements of the other array, and vica-versa.

Comment: But, why won't this be handled by the while loop itself?

Comment: This is more convenience, it also can be handled in while, but in that case you should implement a nested while loop to copy the rest of elements.

Answer (score 0):

That portion is to store leftover elements.
For example if we had

```
A: 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7
B: empty
compare 1, 4
A: *1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7
B: 1
compare 3,4
A: *1, *3, 5, 4, 6, 7
B: 1, 3
compare 5, 4
A: *1, *3, 5, *4, 6, 7
B: 1, 3, 4
compare 5, 6
A: *1, *3, *5, *4, 6, 7
B: 1,3,4,5
```

now that while loop ends because the counter on the first half on A has crossed the pivot. But we are not done , we must add the remaining elements which are leftover from after the pivot, i.e., 6, 7. These we can simply drop into b, they are already sorted by previous calls of merge. That is what the last if statement and loop are for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got what you meant. I was taking the value of pivot wrongly. Thanks again.